# lots of queries - slow?

Tags: php, mysql, cron

To begin with, I apologize if this has been asked already, I could not find anything at least.

Anyway, I'm going to run a cron task each 5 minutes. The script loads 79 external pages, whereas each page contain ~200 values I need to check in database (in total, say 15000 values). 100% of the values will be checked if they exist in database, and if they do (say 10% does) I will use an UPDATE query.

Both queries are very basic, no INNER etc.. It's the first time I use cron and I'm already assuming I will get the response "don't use cron for that" but my host doesn't allow daemons.

The query goes as:

```
SELECT `id`, `date` FROM `users` WHERE `name` = xxx
```

And if there was a match, it will use an UPDATE query (sometimes with additional values).

The question is, will this overload my mysql server? If yes, what are the suggested methods? I'm using PHP if that matters.

Comment: will this overload my mysql server?
It depends on your server ^^

Comment: 15,000 `select` statements and 1,500 `update` commands is a relatively small workload, and shouldn't overload a database with reasonable hardware.  But, it would be a good idea to follow @JonathanKuhn's suggestion, and try to a *set-based solution* instead of a procedural, row by row approach.  Also, make sure that you have appropriate indexes on your tables.

Comment: Oh and what are the "external pages" you are loading? Just files on the server or actually connecting to an external site and downloading a file/list? I would assume that this is where you will have more of a problem if it really is an external page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are just checking the same query over and over, there are a few options. Off the top of my head, you can use `WHERE name IN ('xxx','yyy','zzz','aaa','bbb'...etc)`. Other than that, you could possibly do a file import into another table and probably run one query to do an insert/update.

Update:

```
//This is what I'm assuming your data looks like after loading/parsing all the pages.
//if not, it should be similar.
$data = array(
    'server 1'=>array('aaa','bbb','ccc'),
    'server 2'=>array('xxx','yyy','zzz'),
    'server 3'=>array('111','222', '333'));
//where the key is the name of the server and the value is an array of names.

//I suggest using a transaction for this.
mysql_query("SET AUTOCOMMIT=0");
mysql_query("START TRANSACTION");
//update online to 0 for all. This is why you need transactions. You will set online=1
//for all online below.
mysql_query("UPDATE `table` SET `online`=0");
foreach($data as $serverName=>$names){
    $sql = "UPDATE `table` SET `online`=1,`server`='{$serverName}' WHERE `name` IN ('".implode("','", $names)."')";
    $result = mysql_query($sql);
    //if the query failed, rollback all changes
    if(!$result){
        mysql_query("ROLLBACK");
        die("Mysql error with query: $sql");
    }
}
mysql_query("COMMIT");
```

Comment: It's not the same query, the query is using the values retrieved from the loaded website...

Comment: by "same query" I mean the same query with a different value. The entire query is the same except for `xxx` changes. Does the loaded website have multiple terms that you will search for that you can simply load into an `IN` statement?

Comment: Also, it won't work as I have to check if they are in the database and then update it... And update values may vary depending on db result

Comment: Actually, do you have an example of what the data looks like that you get from the external page? I just need to know what format it is and what the update will look like.

Comment: Simply, it will check if a certain name exists in the database. If it does, it will update X value (always)... But if this row was just added to the database (missing value Y) it will have to update Y as well.

There is 79 pages. Each page has a "title"
Each page has ~200 values to be loaded.
It will check the database if each of these values exist (name matched). If they do, it will update it with another value (call it X). And if this matched row is missing value "Y" (null) it will also update value Y to the row (also part of one of the ~200 values) 

u can see the "values" as array[1]

Comment: without knowing the data structure, I can't write example code without just assuming what the data looks like. If I told you "I get data from an external page, build me a query" could you without knowing the data?

Comment: I updated my comment, see if that makes anything more clear... I'm afraid if I give you the page it will tell you nothing. Read my above comment, but I wrote something wrong. Ignore the "array" part and also the value "Y" is what I refered to as "title"

Comment: If you are at the point where you are searching the database and updating values I'm assuming you are already grabbing the values from the external page. A simple dump of two or three rows from the data array would suffice. A simple `array(0=>array('name'=>'xxx','updateTo'=>'yyy'))` would work and is what I am asking for.

Comment: Alright, I'll see if the website will help you anything.

http://www.tibia.com/community/?subtopic=worlds

This is the list of the "79" pages I'm loading. Enter one of them, then as you can see, inside of it there is names. These are the names I check for in the database. If they exist, I update the row with "online = 1". And I will also check if "server" is NULL in this row, in which case I would also set "server = X", where server is the "&world=" in the URL

Comment: And if the name doesn't exist in the database do you just skip it or insert it?

Comment: I'm writing something now to help, you really just need to do something like `UPDATE table SET online=1,server='Server Name' WHERE name in ('aaa', 'bbb', 'ccc')`. What do you use for database connection? mysql_* functions, pdo or mysqli?

Comment: mysql_

But it's not bad to put 200 values insi de the "in" ?? And is it no extra load to update the "server" for all rows instead of doing it occasionally only ? Only about 5% or less will update the server field

Comment: alright, that is what I would suggest. And putting 200 values inside the IN is not great, but better than 200 individual queries. If you run into trouble, you can break that in statement in groups of 50/100/whatever and just a few more queries.

Comment: You are already doing an update, the "load" is in updating any field. The difference between updating one field and two when they are both fairly short in data is minimal.

Comment: With the exception of loading/parsing the different world pages, even for 79 pages of data in an array, the code i wrote should loop over and do all the updates in milliseconds. The loading/parsing of the pages will take the most time and will most likely be where you run into trouble.

Comment: I did not see tjat you updated the post, thanks for that code! I did not know this was possible, so myself I did online = 2 and at the end, when all queries were updated I did "SET online = online - 1 WHERE online > 0" but I suppose yours is better!

Answer (score 0):

**About MySQL and lot of queries**

If you have enough rights on this server - you may try to increase Query Cache.

You can do it in SQL or in mysql config file.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/query-cache-configuration.html

```
 mysql> SET GLOBAL query_cache_size = 1000000;
 Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.04 sec)

 mysql> SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'query_cache_size';
 +------------------+--------+
 | Variable_name    | Value  |
 +------------------+--------+
 | query_cache_size | 999424 |
 +------------------+--------+
 1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

**Task sheduler in MySQL**

If your updates may work only on data stored in database (there are no PHP variables) - consider using `EVENT` in MySQL instead of running SQL scripts from PHP.

Comment: Task sheduler is not an option, as mentioned I need to load data from another website. Is there a way to see how much of query cache my queries use?